# operator confusion? ! at beginning of a statement

Tags: java

```
int d = -4;
int e = 3;
int g = 0;

!( d > e ) || ( g == -2 )
```

My professor gave me a netbeans file to use for practice operrators and i generally dont have 2 many issues but this one has me confused as hell.

I am supposed to determine if the statement is true or false

I know that ! means no but its usually written differently such as
    d!=3

Ive never seen the ! operator at the beggining of a statement like this and im not sure how to read it.

Can someone explain to me how to approach this?

I dont neccessarily need the answer I just need to know how im supposed to read it cause I see it as

not d greater then e is g equals -2? true false
this statement just does not make sense to me

Comment: `!` can be applied to boolean expressions.

Comment: Maybe this will help: `!(d > e)` is the same thing as `d <= e`

Comment: you can do ( d <= e ) || ( g == -2 ) instead of !( d > e ) || ( g == -2 )

Comment: Don't try to read it like English. It's math; read it as a mathematical expression.

Comment: The `!` before a boolean is a unary "logical complement operator" (it reverses the truth of the following boolean) - see [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html).

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me, i was not aware they all meant the same thing that is was just being written in different ways, the help is much appreciated gents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!` by itself (formally known as *unary*) isn't the same as `!=`. The `!` operator negates what comes immediately after it.

In your case, that would be `( d > e )`, so effectively `!( d > e )` is the same as `( d <= e )`

Answer (score 3):

This is true.. because -4 > 3 and you are operating not on it.
so its

```
( true || (other code) )
```

now as || is short circuit operator and at left side its true its not going to take care of that (other_code) and provide you true value.

Answer (score 0):

! can be used like that it means the same thing as i!=1 as !(i=1) . If the ! serves as a no the first one is saying i is not equal to 1 and second one is saying that i is equal to one is false. Its the same thing except expressed differently